# Check if user has avatar

Tags: posts, functions, post-meta

I want to show author avatar in post info. So I use

```
<?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) , 80); ?>
```

But how can I check if user has avatar?

Answer (score 1):

`get_avatar()` returns An img element for the user's avatar or false on failure. The function does not output anything; you have to echo the return value.

so you can try something like that

```
if( get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) == 0) {
   // no img code
} else {
   echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) , 80 );
}
```

Comment: Downvote, doesn't work $output = ( get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'email' ) ) == 0) ? et_divi_post_meta() : et_divi_post_meta_custom();

Answer (score -1):

this should do what you need:

```
if( get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ){
    echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) , '64' );
}else{
    echo '<img alt="no-image" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149071.svg" class="avatar avatar-64 photo" height="64" width="64">';
}
```

Comment: Downvote, doesn't work    $output = ! get_avatar( get_current_user_id() ) ? et_divi_post_meta() : et_divi_post_meta_custom();

Comment: @Dev the answers to the question are correct, your suggestion results in:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function et_divi_post_meta().

Your suggestion only works if you are working with "ElegantThemes" themes

Comment: It doesn't matter what theme i test with, your code doesn't work. It doesn't check whether there's a user avatar or not. It shows the logged in users avatar but not the authors avatar when logged out.